# How to move a project from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to move my C++ project to Visual Studio 2012; I solved problems and can build and create the exe. But an error, `msvcp80d.dll missing` happens. I think that's a Visual Studio 2005 dll so I want to remove the dependency on that and get past the error. How can I do that?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Are you still linking in DLLs that were still built in 2005 in debug mode?

Comment: Clearly you still have a dependency on code that was originally built with VS2005.  Probably stored in a .lib that you link.  You'll need to rebuild that code as well.

Comment: yes unfortunately there is an third party dll linked msvcp80d.dll or its release version.i found a visual studio tool mage.exe can change manifest vs.so can i change its depedency and relink to msvc110 dlls ?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to search your intermediate build folder for string `msvcp80d.dll` to see which file picks it up.   If all, then look in your .vcxproj file and the .props files it imports.

If it's not found at all then you have an indirect tie, use `depends.exe` on your executable to see which other dll depends on this one. (You may do it right at start.)

Comment: Ok I checked and as I told this dll is missing because new environment is not visual studio 2005 environment.I installed some 2005 distributables but yet it cant find the missing debug dlls...how can i solve ?

Comment: There are no debug distributables, and the license under which you can distribute the release distributables doesn't allow you to distribute the debug runtime binaries.